# O pronome indefinido "todo" concorda com o quê?

Tags: gramática

Qual frase está gramaticalmente correta?

> 1. *Todo* filho e primo *meu* são bonitos.
> 2. *Todos* filho e primo *meu* são bonitos.
> 3. *Todo* filho e primo *meus* são bonitos.
> 4. *Todos* filho e primo *meus* são bonitos.

Eu gostaria, se possível, de uma explicação com referências.

Comment: eu acho que o *meu* deveria tbm ser no plural.

Comment: Agora eu tenho 2 dúdivas. Adicionei os casos que você destacou. Obrigado.

Comment: Se vai deixar filho e primo no singular, o certo seria Todo filho e primo meu são bonitos. Se quiser usar *Todos*, deveria usar filhos e primos e meus no plural. Mas tbm acho q o significado no final é diferente

Comment: Você tem alguma referência que corrobore com o seu raciocínio? Não consegui encontrar uma regra até o momento

Comment: não tenho, por isso, apenas comentei. É o que me parece certo como falante nativo. Eu acho q se colocar o Todo no singular é como existisse um outro *todo*  para a palavra primo...Todo filho e (todo) primo meu são bonitos.

Comment: Em Portugal terias que usar artigos antes de filho/s e primo/s; e o meu/s viria antes do substantivo; a frase ficaria substancialmente diferente.

Comment: @ANeves  No Brasil também soaria bem melhor assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, a maior parte da confusão vem do fato do verbo "ser" estar com sua conjugação errada:
As frases em questão ficam:

• Todo filho e primo meu é bonitos;

• *Todos filho e primo meu são/é bonito(s);

• *Todo filho e primo meus são bonitos;

• *Todos filho e primo meus são bonitos.

A primeira é a mais gramatical, sendo "todo" determinante de filho (e, apesar de não emitido foneticamente, de filho), isto é, coletiviza os termos que estão que por ele são dominados. Funciona mais ou menos como um artigo. Como todo se refere a UM coletivo, usa-se a terceira pessoa do singular. Na segunda frase, ao usar "todos" é o mesmo que dizer "*os filho e primo são..." (algo que ocorre em certos dialetos do centroeste do Brasil). Na terceira, não há plural para que "meus" concorde. E a quarta é uma soma das duas últimas.

Assim, "Todo filho e todo primo meu é bonito" (singular pois não há plural), funciona como "O filho e o primo meu é bonito" (novamente, sem plural).